# Can't parse JSON with object collections

Tags: json, gson

I am new to JSON/GSON but not to Java... been researching but haven't found a clear answer and am getting myself more confused. Please bear with me. Could be my object model is not quite right but will note that if the top-level class (ConvergedNetwork) has either CircuitId or Circuits gson.fromJson() works fine. It's only when the co-habitate in this class I get a null.

I have the following JSON document (target.json)

```
{
    "convergedNetwork": {
        "circuitId": "58/VPXX/102866/TWCS",
        "circuits": {
            "circuit": [
                {
                    "ZLocOid": 9010827045013519707,
                    "circuitId": "58/YHXX/105464/TWCS"
                },
                {
                    "ZLocOid": 9011240550013130225,
                    "circuitId": "58/YHXX/105404/TWCS"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And my bean classes are:

```
package beans;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ConvergedNetwork {
    @SerializedName("convergedNetwork")

    private Circuits circuits;  

    private CircuitId circuitId;
    public CircuitId getCircuitId() {
        return circuitId;
    }

    public void setCircuitId(CircuitId circuitId) {
        this.circuitId = circuitId;
    }

    public Circuits getCircuits() {
        return circuits;
    }

    public void setCircuits(Circuits circuits) {
        this.circuits = circuits;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ConvergedNetwork [circuits=" + circuits + ", circuitId="
                + circuitId + "]";
    }

}

package beans;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Circuits {

        @SerializedName("circuits")
        private Circuit circuit;

        public Circuit getCircuit() {
            return circuit;
        }

        public void setCircuit(Circuit circuit) {
            this.circuit = circuit;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Circuits: " +circuit.toString()+ "]";
        }


}

package beans;

import java.util.Arrays;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Circuit {

        @SerializedName("circuit")

        private ckt[] ckts;

        public ckt[] getCkts() {
            return ckts;
        }

        public void setCkts(ckt[] ckts) {
            this.ckts = ckts;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Circuit [ckts=" + Arrays.toString(ckts) + "]";

        }
        class ckt
        {
          long ZLocOid;
          String circuitId;
          public long getZLocOid() {
            return ZLocOid;
          }
            public void setZLocOid(long zLocOid) {
                ZLocOid = zLocOid;
            }
            public String getCircuitId() {
                return circuitId;
            }
            public void setCircuitId(String circuitId) {
                this.circuitId = circuitId;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "ckt [ circuitId=" + circuitId + ", ZLocOid=" + ZLocOid+ "]" ;
            }
        }
}


package beans;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CircuitId {
    @SerializedName("circuitId")

    private String circuitId;

    public String getCircuitId() {
        return circuitId;
    }
    public void setCircuitId(String circuitId) {
        this.circuitId = circuitId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Circuit [circuitId=" + circuitId + "]";
    }

}
```

And when I run the following:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create(); 
String fileData = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("target.json"))); ConvergedNetwork obj = gson.fromJson(fileData, ConvergedNetwork.class);
System.out.println("\n\n Obj: "+obj.getClass()+ "\n\n" + obj.toString());
```

I get the following:

```
ConvergedNetwork [circuits=Circuits: Circuit [ckts=[ckt [ circuitId=58/YHXX/105464/TWCS, ZLocOid=0], ckt [ circuitId=58/YHXX/105404/TWCS, ZLocOid=9011240550013130225]]]], circuitId=null]
```

You'll notice that it successfully parsted the circuits objects but not the circuitId object. Is it because one of the members inside the ckt class is also named circuitId? Or do I need to write a Adapter class to help GSON along?

Answer (score 0):

Without digging into it too much it looks like your JSON is missing a couple of `"`'s.

For example: `9011240550013130225` needs to be `"9011240550013130225"`

Also `ZLocOid` is missing a starting `"`

Comment: My bad. the ZLocOid needs the ".. Somehow I deleted that when copying/pasting. I fixed it above. Numbers, even longs, are supported in JSON docs.

Comment: Did you wrap the numbers in `"`'s?

Comment: The above returned: ConvergedNetwork [circuits=Circuits: Circuit [ckts=[ckt [ circuitId=58/YHXX/105464/TWCS, ZLocOid=9010827045013519707], ckt [ circuitId=58/YHXX/105404/TWCS, ZLocOid=9011240550013130225]]]], circuitId=null] so that's not the issue... it's the circuitId=null that isn't working

Comment: I mean in the original the `"ZLocOid"`values are not wrapped in quotes. Have you tried it with those values wrapped in quotes? I know it sounds silly, but strict JSON standard requires all keys and values to be wrapped in quotes.  Many parsers still work, but it might be causing GSON a problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your JSON, `circuitId` is a `String`.

```
{
"convergedNetwork": {
    "circuitId": "58/VPXX/102866/TWCS",
...
```

You've created a class (`CircuitId`) that *contains* a `String` field named `circuitId` and are trying to map to it. That's not going to work. That JSON would look like:

```
"circuitId": {"circuitId":"58/VPXX/102866/TWCS"},
```

In your other class (`pks`) you're just using a `String` which is why it works.

Change your top level class to:

```
public class ConvergedNetwork {

     private Circuits circuits;  
     private String circuitId;
     ...
```

Then it'll map correctly.

**Edit to add:** You also have issues with your `@SerializedName` annotations. The only one you need is inside the `Circuit` class for that `ckts` array. Get rid of all the others.

Comment: I changed the top level class like this: public class ConvergedNetwork {
 @SerializedName("convergedNetwork")
        private Circuits circuits;  
 private String circuitId; .... } And I still got the same issue (circuitId = null)  : ConvergedNetwork [circuits=Circuits: Circuit [ckts=[ckt [ circuitId=58/YHXX/105464/TWCS, ZLocOid=9010827045013519707], ckt [ circuitId=58/YHXX/105404/TWCS, ZLocOid=9011240550013130225]]]], circuitId=null]

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help me out!!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issues. First of all, the annotations were wrong. For some reason I thought they were for the name of the object class not the member field. Hit me on the head. Another issue I fixed was I was missing a top-level container class so all of the objects could be parsed. I created a 'Data' class that held the ConvergedNetwork class.  Chalk all this up to amateur mistakes as I was new to GSON/JSON.